# Css - Draw rectangle with rounded corners as background

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Is any ways to make this figure with only html & css?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost the same solution as @pedram, but using pseudo element in order to avoid **inverse skewing** the content inside the div (if there will be a content) :

```css
div.content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
div.content:before { 
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    background: #ff8f00;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transform: skew(-5deg);
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:-1;
]
```

```html
<div class="content">
lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `transform skew` like below, and your shape called `Parallelogram`

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ff8f00;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transform: skew(-5deg); /* OR transform: skew(-190deg); */
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: @bhansa This works too, not `-20` but `transform: skew(-10deg);` works.